# pulling database and update database - php

Tags: php, mysql, edit

I have rows showing products and their stockings.
I can pull out records from the database but somehow I am stuck at the editing part.  When I click on edit I don't know how to pass the id so I can use the id to select what is needed to be selected in the table.

I have something like stock.php which shows all item_name and stock

```
    <?php
        $sql    = "SELECT * FROM inventory";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

    //make sure database queries
    if (!$result) {
        echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
        echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table><tr><td>Name</td>
                         <td>Stock</td>
                     </tr>";
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>".$row["item_name"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["stock"]."</td>
                    <td>
                        <form action='edit.php' method='POST'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='$id' value='$id'/>
                            <input type='submit' name='edit' value='edit' />
                        </form>
                    </td>
                 </tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
?>
```

in my edit.php I have something like this which is giving me error because the `$id` is not passed

```
include_once "init.php";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    // query the table by matching up the int id
    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id = '$id'";
}
```

I want to pull out the data again in a new page and then having input box again to let users update stock # or even the product name and others if necessary.

Comment: use $_POST['id'] instead $id and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your input declaration.  HTML items can't have names that start with special characters (like the $).  You should be setting the variable-based names this way:

```
<input type='hidden' name='".$id."' value='".$id."'/>
```

Also in your edit.php, your SQL statement has a bug.

```
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id = '$id'";
```

should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id = ".intval($id);
```

Comment: The SQL statement would work with the quotes too, but you should definitely use `$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id = ".intval($id);` to avoid injections or errors when `$id` is not an integer. Unless you have `$id = intval($_POST['id'])` before ,which you would need at same point anyway since `register_globals` are a thing from the past

Comment: yes!  you must screen your user input/session variables before querying your database using htmlspecialchars or something of that nature.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` will do nothing against SQL injections but http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php or generally speaking, prepared statements, will

Comment: Still, in you answer, `$id` will be undefined when `register_globals` is off (99% of today's PHP servers I guess)

Comment: I did change to all these though but still `$id` can not be passed over and still giving me the `Undefined variable`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following updates:

stock.php

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'/>
```

edit.php

```
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id = '".$_POST["id"]."'";
```

you are passing the current id value as the post var name, the var's name should be "id"